# wants to populate two drop down boxes on previous selected option

Tags: javascript, html, hidden, dropdown

I am working on a very old coded project but it is running perfectly  on selected option.The coder populate one hidden drop down which is dynamic like this.

```
            <td class="hidden isagentname"><strong>
              <select name="agentnamee">
                <option value="">Please AgentName</option>
                  <?php $i = 0; while($i < $buyerCodeNum){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo 
                  mysql_result($buyerCode,$i,"name"); ?>"><?php echo 
                  mysql_result($buyerCode,$i,"name"); ?>
                </option>
                  <?php $i++;}?>
              </select>
              <a href="#" class="remove" rel="agentname">remove</a>
              </strong>
            </td>
```

now i want to populate two hidden drop down boxes on  selected option from first drop down box

i tried this but it is not working

```
using two <td> under one select tag
```

kindly genius coders help me

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#agentName').hide();
 $('#agentID').hide();
    $('#purpose').on('change', function() {
      if (this.value > 0)
      {   
       $('#agentName').show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#agentName").hide();
      }
    });
 $("#agentName").on('click', function() {
      if (this.value > 0)
      {  
       $('#agentID').show();
      }
     else
      {
        $("#agentID").hide();
      }
   });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id='purpose'>
<option value="1">Personal use</option>
<option value="2">Business use</option>
<option value="3">Passing on to a client</option>
</select>
<div style='display:none;' id='business'>Business Name</div>

 <select name="agentnamee" id="agentName">
 <option value="0">Please AgentName</option>
  <option value="1">zzz</option>
  <option value="2">xxx</option>
   <option value="3">yyy</option>
                    
                    </select>
                    <a href="#" class="remove" rel="agentname">remove</a>
      <select name="agentID" id="agentID">
 <option value="0">Please AgentID</option>
   <option value="1">1xxx</option>
  <option value="2">2xxx</option>
   <option value="3">3yyy</option>
                    
                    </select>



</body>
</html>
```

YOu meant something like this? Onclicking the first dropdown option it will open second dropdown and so on?